# Uncaught ReferenceError: <function> is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):15)

Tags: javascript, html, button

Trying to generate a new random SKU from the array of objects on each click, but keep receiving a `ReferenceError`.

Here is my approach:

```
// example of the data 

         [{sku: '101ZS536',
            price: 4.37
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 42.61
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 53.31
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 0
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 3.46
          }
        ]
```

```
//index.html

            <div class="container">
               <input type="button" id="SKUsearch" value="Search" onclick="randomSKU()" />
              <p id="message" ></p>
          </div>
```

```
//index.js
function bootRentData(bookData) {

   bookData.forEach((book) => {
    //generate random sku number

      const sku = book.sku
      function randomSKU(){
        var random = sku[Math.floor(Math.random() * sku.length)];
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = sku[random];
      }


      });
        wrap.innerHTML += `<tr>
                             <td>${book.sku}</td>
                             <td>${book.price}</td>
                          </tr>`
   }
```

Lead me to the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: randomSKU is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):15)
```

Comment: have you close `const sku = book.sku`   with `;` ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini that shouldn't make a difference. What does the rest of `index.js` look like?

Comment: `index.js` has to be included before the `<input type="button"...>` -> Please add a [mcve]

Comment: @Pointy i try it, yes you have right.

Comment: Just edited my HTML code

Comment: @Andreas are you referring to the script?

Comment: I see no reason for this to happen unless either `index.js` is not loading correctly (perhaps your path is wrong), or there is an error elsewhere in the file which stops the function from being defined. Are there any other errors in the console?

Comment: @Andreas in this case the positioning of the `index.js` script doesn't matter, the function only needs to be defined at the point where the button is clicked, which it will be (assuming no problems in loading or parsing the script).

Comment: @RobinZigmond if I take this function, my code runs just the way it supposed to. Nothing on the console, just this reference error.

Comment: And are you sure that this function is defined in global scope, as opposed to inside some function? (One of the many disadvantages of inline `on***` handlers is that they can only access global variables.)

Comment: Again, is that the *entire* `index.js` script, or just a part of it?

Comment: No, I've other functions, this is just part of it. I'll try to edit it.  @Pointy

Comment: @Pointy Just edited the index.js, what do you think?

Comment: That's your problem. Your event handler function is defined **inside** another function. It is therefore not global and not visible as an event handler via an element attribute.

Comment: Any suggestions to make this work? @Pointy

Comment: Not really; the code doesn't make much sense. You're defining the function *inside* the `.forEach()` handler; even if the function were visible, what does that mean? There would be a separate function per `book`.

Comment: Is it possible to have onclick event without the function? I'm just trying to randomly generate the SKU numbers using a button. @Pointy